# copying from "window.prompt" in chrome copies the message, not the text, with ctrl+c

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a setup where I if you hit a button, selected text is copied to clipboard (for IE).  The selection of the text works, however since every browser but IE doesn't allow copying to clipboard, I have the workaround

```
window.prompt ("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text); 
//where text is the selected text being passed
```

This works perfectly for firefox, however in Chrome, for some reason, when you copy the text with ctrl+c, "Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter" is copied, not what is in text.

Any ideas about this?

Comment: not using Chrome 12.0.742.112, works like a charm

Comment: yeah, I'm not having a problem with it either

Comment: It only copies the message when you focus the buttons. By default the text inside the textbox is selected and copying works just fine.

Comment: Works perfectly find in Chrome. check out http://jsfiddle.net/4LB4b/ using v12.0.742.112

Comment: Okay, I have v2.0.172.43.  Yes old, but it took 3+ weeks to get this cleared at work, getting most current is not possible here.  So your saying with v12 chrome has no problem?  
then I'll just have an if that starts at v12.0.0.0 allowing the prompt, anything less gets alert to copy by hand
(this is for people working at home over vpn and don't use IE [like Linux/Mac users or people using chrome/firefox on windows] so I doubt anyone else has chrome v2 haha